# Not sure how to change the behavior of my CSS Grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Edit: Due to the requests I have uploaded a code snippet of my website:

```js
const logo = document.querySelector(".logo-link img"),
  myNav = document.querySelector(".main-navbar"),
  navigationToggler = document.querySelector(".nav-toggler"),
  dropShadow = document.querySelector("#dropshadow"),
  hamburgerBtn = document.querySelector(".hamburger");

window.onscroll = scrolled;



function scrolled() {
  if ((document.body.scrollTop >= 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 10)) {
    logo.src = "../imgs/logo/logo-lightgrey.png";
    myNav.classList.add("scroll");
  } else if (hamburgerBtn.className.includes("is-active") == 0) {
    logo.src = "../imgs/logo/logo-black.png";
    myNav.classList.remove("scroll");
  }
};

hamburgerBtn.addEventListener('click', hamburgerToggled);

function hamburgerToggled() {
  if (hamburgerBtn.className.includes("is-active") != 0) {
    myNav.classList.remove("navbar-override");
    dropShadow.classList.remove("drop-shadow");
    dropshadow.style.display = "none";
    hamburgerBtn.classList.remove("is-active");

    scrolled();

  } else {
    myNav.classList.add("navbar-override");
    dropShadow.classList.add("drop-shadow");
    dropshadow.style.display = "block";
    hamburgerBtn.classList.add("is-active");
    logo.src = "../imgs/logo/logo-lightgrey.png";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-image: url("../imgs/general-bg/subtle-pattern.png");
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4rem 25rem auto 4rem;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "hero-section" "main-content" "footer";
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.about-us__hero-section {
  grid-area: hero-section;
  background-image: url(https://serving.photos.photobox.com/68808029c7b0524783bf789e026f6ff67adc1cd6c7e8c75c22b01f97caf5a1b264747b1f.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 8%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 29rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.about-us__hero-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 17%;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.about-us__hero-info h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.about-us__hero-info p {
  margin-top: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.main-navbar {
  top: 0;
  grid-area: header;
}

main.about-content {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 7%);
  grid-template-areas: "A A A A A A B B B B B B" "C C C C C C D D D D D D" "E E E E E E F F F F F F" "G G G G G G H H H H H H";
  column-gap: 1%;
  grid-area: main-content;
  max-width: 1392px;
}

.employee-container p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.employee-container h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.employee-img-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.gif-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.employee-container:hover .gif-image {
  display: block;
}

.employee-container:hover {
  border: 1px dashed #60b0e2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.employee-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.employee-info {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.employee-info .employee-img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 10px;
  object-position: 50% 0;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

.main-footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.scroll {
  background-color: #211d1c;
}

.scroll .hamburger-inner,
.scroll .hamburger-inner::before,
.scroll .hamburger-inner::after {
  background: #d1c9c3;
}


/* Employees */

.employee1 {
  grid-area: A;
}

.employee2 {
  grid-area: B;
}

.employee3 {
  grid-area: C;
}

.employee4 {
  grid-area: D;
}

.employee5 {
  grid-area: E;
}

.employee6 {
  grid-area: F;
}

.employee7 {
  grid-area: G;
}

.employee8 {
  grid-area: H;
}


/* Employees */

@media (min-width: 46rem) {
  main.about-content {
    grid-template-areas: "A A A A B B B B C C C C" "D D D D E E E E F F F F" ". . G G G G H H H H . .";
    column-gap: 1%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
  main.about-content {
    grid-template-areas: "A A A B B B C C C D D D" "E E E F F F G G G H H H"
  }
}


/* ALL THE CSS CODE FROM SHARED.CSS */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya:wght@400;500;800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.drop-shadow {
  background-image: url(imgs/general-bg/dark_embroidery.png);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

#dropshadow {
  display: none;
}

#dropshadow nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.mobile-nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 6rem;
  left: 2.3rem;
}

.mobile-nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #d1c9c3;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-nav-item a:hover,
.mobile-nav-item a:active {
  color: white;
}

.mobile-nav-main-item a:hover,
.mobile-nav-main-item a:active {
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
}

.mobile-nav-main-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2.1rem;
  display: block;
  color: #d1c9c3;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #d1c9c3;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem;
}

.nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d1c9c3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  z-index: 100;
}


/*                       */


/* Hamburger Icon below */

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2rem;
  left: 1.1rem;
  width: 3rem;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: .3rem;
}

.hamburger-box {
  width: 60%;
  height: 1.4rem;
}

.hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Hamburger Icon above */


/*                     */

.main-navbar nav {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.brand {
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo-link {
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.logo-link img {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #d1c9c3;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 33%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-item:hover,
.nav-item:active {
  background: #5cb57d;
}


/* Footer */

.main-footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: #131110;
  color: #d1c9c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.footer-list {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right-reserved p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.navbar-override {
  transition-duration: 0ms;
  background-color: #211d1c;
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
  .main-navbar {
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 6rem;
  }
  .logo-link {
    height: 4rem;
  }
  button.hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-navbar nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Experiment 1</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="../hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../shared.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="about-style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dropshadow">
    <nav>
      <ul class="mobile-nav-list">
        <li class="mobile-nav-item">
          <a href="../main-index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-nav-item">
          <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-nav-item">
          <a href="../main-index.html">Contact us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-nav-main-item">
          <a href="../main-index.html">Product menu</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <header class="main-navbar">
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
          <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
      </button>
    <div class="brand">
      <a class="logo-link" href="#">
        <img src="../imgs/logo/logo-black.png" alt="logo-brand-image">
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="../main-index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="../about/about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="../about/about.html">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="about-us__hero-section">
    <div class="about-us__hero-info">
      <h1>Meet Our Team</h1>
      <p>These are the people that make the magic happen.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <main class="about-content">
    <div class="employee-container employee1">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img"     src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/S3sc3Pg9dFpUA/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Jennie Kimbel</h4>
        <p>CEO</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee2">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/gIfv29q3ULtqjYTR7B/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Alex Shiff</h4>
        <p>Web Designer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee3">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/1iTnzFRFQwDpv3C8/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Anthony Smith</h4>
        <p>Customer Service</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee4">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/q6RoNkLlFNjaw/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Hermy Shanders</h4>
        <p>CPO</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee5">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xUPGcqN9laat2ooiJi/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Abdul Mubarak</h4>
        <p>Janitor</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee6">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/EsmlrgWNx5v0Y/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Mark Robert</h4>
        <p>Marketing Director</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee7">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/Ni4cpi0uUkd6U/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Iestyn Etik</h4>
        <p>Web developer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee8">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/UWRyZHCsHtBFS/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Haley Ford</h4>
        <p>Customer Service</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="main-footer">
    <nav>
      <ul class="footer-list">
        <li class="footer-item">Support</li>
        <li class="footer-item">Terms of use</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="right-reserved">
      <p>©2020 - m3supplies. All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="about-script.js" async defer></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I am somewhat new to CSS Grid, and I am not sure how to fix my problem:

So, as you can see from the code and the picture below, my overall page layout consists of a header, hero-section, main-content and the footer.

Additionally, my "main-content" also has the display:grid property.

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4rem 25rem auto 4rem;
  grid-template-areas: "header"
                       "hero-section"
                       "main-content"
                       "footer";
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[image]

So, on normal 100% zoom, my page looks fine, however, as I zoom out since my main-content section's height is set to auto, I get a big separation between the two rows that I have within my "main-content" section:

[image]

I was wondering whether anyone knows how I can change this behaviour so that the two rows within the main-content section remain close to each other.
P.S. I did try changing the value of auto to minmax but I couldn't figure out anything that worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create a snippet with SO tools please `<>`

Comment: Can you pls post your code on jsfiddle or codepen ? Because the information you have provided is really litte.

Comment: I have now included a code snippet of the website (had to use the same image for all the "employees" due to all of my images being saved locally on my computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [`align-items: flex-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) to `body`. This working fine.

```js
const logo = document.querySelector(".logo-link img"),
  myNav = document.querySelector(".main-navbar"),
  navigationToggler = document.querySelector(".nav-toggler"),
  dropShadow = document.querySelector("#dropshadow"),
  hamburgerBtn = document.querySelector(".hamburger");

window.onscroll = scrolled;



function scrolled() {
  if ((document.body.scrollTop >= 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 10)) {
    logo.src = "../imgs/logo/logo-lightgrey.png";
    myNav.classList.add("scroll");
  } else if (hamburgerBtn.className.includes("is-active") == 0) {
    logo.src = "../imgs/logo/logo-black.png";
    myNav.classList.remove("scroll");
  }
};

hamburgerBtn.addEventListener('click', hamburgerToggled);

function hamburgerToggled() {
  if (hamburgerBtn.className.includes("is-active") != 0) {
    myNav.classList.remove("navbar-override");
    dropShadow.classList.remove("drop-shadow");
    dropshadow.style.display = "none";
    hamburgerBtn.classList.remove("is-active");

    scrolled();

  } else {
    myNav.classList.add("navbar-override");
    dropShadow.classList.add("drop-shadow");
    dropshadow.style.display = "block";
    hamburgerBtn.classList.add("is-active");
    logo.src = "../imgs/logo/logo-lightgrey.png";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-image: url("../imgs/general-bg/subtle-pattern.png");
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4rem 25rem auto 4rem;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "hero-section" "main-content" "footer";
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.about-us__hero-section {
  grid-area: hero-section;
  background-image: url(https://serving.photos.photobox.com/68808029c7b0524783bf789e026f6ff67adc1cd6c7e8c75c22b01f97caf5a1b264747b1f.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 8%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 29rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.about-us__hero-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 17%;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.about-us__hero-info h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.about-us__hero-info p {
  margin-top: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.main-navbar {
  top: 0;
  grid-area: header;
}

main.about-content {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 7%);
  grid-template-areas: "A A A A A A B B B B B B" "C C C C C C D D D D D D" "E E E E E E F F F F F F" "G G G G G G H H H H H H";
  column-gap: 1%;
  grid-area: main-content;
  max-width: 1392px;
}

.employee-container p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.employee-container h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.employee-img-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.gif-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.employee-container:hover .gif-image {
  display: block;
}

.employee-container:hover {
  border: 1px dashed #60b0e2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.employee-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.employee-info {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.employee-info .employee-img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 10px;
  object-position: 50% 0;
  transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

.main-footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.scroll {
  background-color: #211d1c;
}

.scroll .hamburger-inner,
.scroll .hamburger-inner::before,
.scroll .hamburger-inner::after {
  background: #d1c9c3;
}


/* Employees */

.employee1 {
  grid-area: A;
}

.employee2 {
  grid-area: B;
}

.employee3 {
  grid-area: C;
}

.employee4 {
  grid-area: D;
}

.employee5 {
  grid-area: E;
}

.employee6 {
  grid-area: F;
}

.employee7 {
  grid-area: G;
}

.employee8 {
  grid-area: H;
}


/* Employees */

@media (min-width: 46rem) {
  main.about-content {
    grid-template-areas: "A A A A B B B B C C C C" "D D D D E E E E F F F F" ". . G G G G H H H H . .";
    column-gap: 1%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
  main.about-content {
    grid-template-areas: "A A A B B B C C C D D D" "E E E F F F G G G H H H"
  }
}


/* ALL THE CSS CODE FROM SHARED.CSS */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya:wght@400;500;800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.drop-shadow {
  background-image: url(imgs/general-bg/dark_embroidery.png);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

#dropshadow {
  display: none;
}

#dropshadow nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.mobile-nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 6rem;
  left: 2.3rem;
}

.mobile-nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #d1c9c3;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobile-nav-item a:hover,
.mobile-nav-item a:active {
  color: white;
}

.mobile-nav-main-item a:hover,
.mobile-nav-main-item a:active {
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
}

.mobile-nav-main-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 2.1rem;
  display: block;
  color: #d1c9c3;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #d1c9c3;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem;
}

.nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d1c9c3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  z-index: 100;
}


/*                       */


/* Hamburger Icon below */

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2rem;
  left: 1.1rem;
  width: 3rem;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: .3rem;
}

.hamburger-box {
  width: 60%;
  height: 1.4rem;
}

.hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Hamburger Icon above */


/*                     */

.main-navbar nav {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.brand {
  width: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo-link {
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.logo-link img {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #d1c9c3;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 33%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-item:hover,
.nav-item:active {
  background: #5cb57d;
}


/* Footer */

.main-footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: #131110;
  color: #d1c9c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.footer-list {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right-reserved p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.navbar-override {
  transition-duration: 0ms;
  background-color: #211d1c;
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
  .main-navbar {
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 6rem;
  }
  .logo-link {
    height: 4rem;
  }
  button.hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-navbar nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Experiment 1</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="../hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../shared.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="about-style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dropshadow">
    <nav>
      <ul class="mobile-nav-list">
        <li class="mobile-nav-item">
          <a href="../main-index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-nav-item">
          <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-nav-item">
          <a href="../main-index.html">Contact us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-nav-main-item">
          <a href="../main-index.html">Product menu</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <header class="main-navbar">
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
          <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
      </button>
    <div class="brand">
      <a class="logo-link" href="#">
        <img src="../imgs/logo/logo-black.png" alt="logo-brand-image">
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="../main-index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="../about/about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="../about/about.html">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="about-us__hero-section">
    <div class="about-us__hero-info">
      <h1>Meet Our Team</h1>
      <p>These are the people that make the magic happen.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <main class="about-content">
    <div class="employee-container employee1">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img"     src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/S3sc3Pg9dFpUA/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Jennie Kimbel</h4>
        <p>CEO</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee2">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/gIfv29q3ULtqjYTR7B/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Alex Shiff</h4>
        <p>Web Designer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee3">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/1iTnzFRFQwDpv3C8/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Anthony Smith</h4>
        <p>Customer Service</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee4">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/q6RoNkLlFNjaw/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Hermy Shanders</h4>
        <p>CPO</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee5">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xUPGcqN9laat2ooiJi/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Abdul Mubarak</h4>
        <p>Janitor</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee6">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/EsmlrgWNx5v0Y/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Mark Robert</h4>
        <p>Marketing Director</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee7">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/Ni4cpi0uUkd6U/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Iestyn Etik</h4>
        <p>Web developer</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="employee-container employee8">
      <div class="employee-info">

        <div class="employee-img-container">
          <img class="employee-img" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/585075754258d926e237de819bf623cbf2d065006e653c4ec7a9e53bd66bb6c3fef67ea6.jpg" alt="employee picture">
          <img class="gif-image" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/UWRyZHCsHtBFS/giphy.gif" alt="gif representing employee's personality">
        </div>

        <h4>Haley Ford</h4>
        <p>Customer Service</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="main-footer">
    <nav>
      <ul class="footer-list">
        <li class="footer-item">Support</li>
        <li class="footer-item">Terms of use</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="right-reserved">
      <p>©2020 - m3supplies. All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="about-script.js" async defer></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know it's possible to use flex-start etc. without setting the display property to flex. Is this because my display is set to grid?

Comment: yes `align-items` and `justify-content` properties can be used with `display:flex` and `display:grid`